# mysql random with condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql, say table1.

I am running this on it:

```
SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table1`
```

This works well, but I am now trying to add a condition of "AND tom".

Where tom is a integer field.

For example:

```
id tom
1   0
2   3
3   2
4   0
5   0
6   3
7   1
8   1
9   3
```

etc.

So, my question is,

How can I pick a random value from id, which also satisfies tom='0' say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM `table1` WHERE tom = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This will first get all rows in which `tom = 0`,then order those results [randomly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). MySQL will then limit those results to just one, returning the single value you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood correctly:

```
SELECT id FROM `table1` WHERE tom = 0 order by rand() limit 1
```

Comment: Why order by 'RAND() limit 1'?  It just returns a single value without it right?

Comment: without it it will return all values for tom = 0 in a random order. With the limit will return the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select * from table where tom = 0 ) as t order by rand() limit 1
```